# How do I delete a input from user in java? I keep getting the same results copied into my new file and it doesn't delete the input

Tags: java

```
@FXML
public void DeleteVendor(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    File oldFile = new File("Vendors2.txt");
    File newFile = new File("VendorList.txt");

    BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(oldFile));
    BufferedWriter writeFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile));

    String vendorRemove = Ven_N.getText();
    String line;

    while ((line = readFile.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] compareLine = line.split("\n");
        if (compareLine.equals(vendorRemove)) {
            continue;
        }else
        writeFile.write(line);
    }
    writeFile.close();
    readFile.close();
}
```

Comment: `compareLine.equals(vendorRemove)` this will *never* be true since you are comparing an *array* with a *single string*.

Comment: Your problem description should be in the question, not in the title only. Your title also isn't very descriptive, mentioning user input when your problem is about files. See [ask]. Finally, why the `line.split` if you're reading with `readLine` anyway?

Comment: I assume 'trim' is what is really wanted instead of 'split'

Comment: Hello, I'm thinking about the String in Java is immutable, so you can't change the value after you initialized it, and I'm sure you know that, I'm suggesting that if you try to add values to a new String for testing purposes only and check if it's deleting, and you are getting the desired changes, if yes then you can write to file as the new String.